# PHP pass a var into $_FILES inside function

Tags: php

I am working on an admin area that will have file uploads on several pages.  Regardless of the name of the form field I want to do some specific processes, but I'm a bit stuck on how to do this in a function.  I have the code below, which I knew going in wouldn't be correct, but I'm not sure how to achieve what I'm trying to do.

```
function fileprocessor ($file)
{
    echo $_FILES['$file']['tmp_name'];
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What *are* you trying to do? I don't understand.

Comment: We need more information. Is this just echoing the name of the file or does it have other actions as well.

Comment: Right now I'm just doing the temp name echo to get it working, no other actions.  What you see above is the whole thing.  If I echo $file (which is a text field) I get the file name that was upload.

Comment: If I do this, it works (as it should):
echo $_FILES[file]['tmp_name'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_FILES is the process of a form submit. to pass it to a function you need to pass the field name through the function.

```
function fileprocessor($file) {
 $name = $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
 echo $name;
}
```

In the Code you will have

```
fileprocessor('userfile'); # Enter field name from upload form
```

This way you can have what ever you may like in the file processor

### EDIT

You can test my version here http://jawilliams.site11.com/filestest.php

Answer (score 2):

```
function fileprocessor ($file)
{
    echo $_FILES[$file]['tmp_name'];
}
```

From [manual](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

**Note**: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of one obvious flaw (can't believe I did that), however it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite common mistake.
Many newbie programmers take single quotes as a part of array syntax.
While it's merely string delimiters and has actually nothing to do with arrays.
This mistake can lead to some funny or dramatic consequences.

So, to use a variable just use this variable, without quotes or other symbols.